# Change from ProgressBar to a ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm trying to check an EditText starting a thread `(AsyncTask)`. This thread starts a ProgressBar. Well, when this thread has finished, I evalue the answer and if it's correct where there was the ProgressBar I need to put some image like "ok", if it's incorrect an image like "error". Always in the same place where the ProgressBar was.

This ProgressBar isn't a Dialog, it's at the right from the EditText

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compose a layout with a ViewSwitcher. The first child view being the ProgressBar, and second the ImageView. You can place the "ok" or "error" image at runtime and call the ViewSwitcher's showNext() method to swap views.

Hope that helps.